# How to convert edgelist to adjacency matrix format and save in csv file?

Tags: r, csv, igraph, sna

I have an edge list of person-to-person data

```
PersonTo,PersonFrom
   P1,P2
   P3,P1
   P4,P6
   P6,P1
```

I want to convert this in adjacency matrix format. I have tried the code given below but it shows output on R screen. How can i save this output in csv format?

```
rm(list=ls())
getwd()
library(igraph)
datafile <- "C:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\dd.csv"
edges <- read.csv(datafile)
head(edges)
as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(edges)))
```

Comment: Have you tried `write.csv`? The output may be what you want, though you might want to set `row.names = FALSE`

Comment: as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(edges)))            write.csv(edges, file = "C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\\ddout.csv", row.names = FALSE)
yes it shows the matrix input file but didnt shows the column names at left side

Comment: No, I mean `write.csv(as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(edges))), file = "C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\\ddout.csv", row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: This command shows this output Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\sakih_000\Desktop\ddout.csv': Permission denied

Comment: then write it to a different file, like just "thisfile.csv", which puts it in your working directory.

Comment: 'm <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph.data.frame(edges)))                 write.csv(m, file = "C:\\Users\\sakih_000\\Desktop\\ddout1t.csv")'"Solved by removing row.names = FALSE)